# Why using Decimal in this CAML Query is not returning correct records?

Tags: development, lookup-column, caml-query, caml

I have the following table:

```
DoubleNumber
-------------
10.50
44.77
88.90
```

I am using the following CAML Query:

```
query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"DoubleNumber\"/><Value Type=\"Decimal\">44</Value></Contains></Where>";
```

Logically speaking, it should return no records. But, I dont understand why it keeps returning the second record.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Contains` you should use `<Gt>` (Greater than) or `Lt` (Less than).

`Contains` operator works with `String` type. Since you are using `decimal` you should always use arithmetic logic operators.

Comment: I thought so too, but was not quite sure. Thanks!